# Ext.ux.Router dynamically trigger route

Tags: javascript, extjs, routes

Is there any way to dynamically trigger the route? If a session is
expired the user is redirected to the login with the route parameter. The route doesn't happen because user is not logged. After the login the route doesn't happen automatically. So I see a possible workaround to manually trigger the route.

https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.ux.Router.redirect(Ext.History.getToken());
```